# When I install Perl 5.30.0 from source, perl -v still displays 5.26.2 is being used

Tags: linux, perl, compile, make

I'm using Linux, and wanted to install the latest version of Perl, as according to the `perl -v` command, I had version 5.26.2, and the latest (stable) release is 5.30.0.  But when I compiled the source, `perl -v` still returned 5.26.2!  Why did this happen?

Here's what I did:

I acquired a copy of the Perl source from [this site](https://www.perl.org/get.html#unix_like), unpacked it, and followed the installation instructions specified in README (the plain one, *not* any of the ones with .os at the end:)

```
./Configure -des -Dprefix=$HOME/localperl
make
make test
make install
```

I then ran `perl -v` to determine whether it worked, and it returned that I still had v5.26.2.

Comment: You might find better answers at unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: Maybe there are two `perl` executables on your path.  Try `type -a perl` to see.

Comment: @KenJackson, what you suggested returned `perl is /usr/bin/perl`.  I'm not sure what this means.

Comment: That's the version that's running, @Blue-Maned Hawk, not the one you compiled in your home directory.  Put this in your `~/.bashrc` file:  `PATH="$HOME/localperl/bin:$PATH"` and execute it: `. $/.bashrc`.  (That's the directory your compiled perl is in, isn't it?)

Comment: I'll try that, and comment again if it works.  Any particular place?

Comment: I added that line to the file, @KenJackson, but the command you suggested, `.$/.bashrc` failed to work.  Did you mean `./.bashrc`?

Comment: That `$` was supposed to be a `~`.  It doesn't allow me to edit it.

Comment: Nevermind.  I fixed it by removing everything after -de.